# jasmine-reporters modifySuiteName not work?

Tags: junit, protractor, jasmine-reporters

I'm using protractor with jasmine-reporters 2.0.7

I tried to use the modifySuiteName option to modify suite names.

This is what in my conf.js:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
browserName: 'firefox'
}, {
browserName: 'chrome'
}],

onPrepare: function() {
  var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
  return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
      var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
          savePath: 'c://scripts',
          filePrefix: browserName,
          consolidateAll: true,
          modifySuiteName: function(generatedSuiteName, suite) {
              return browserName+ '.' + generatedSuiteName;}
      }));
  });
},
```

I suppose to see

> testsuite name="chrome.Demo App"

in chrome.xml

and

> testsuite name="firefox.Demo App"

in firefox.xml

But I can only see

> testsuite name="Demo App"

in both files.

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Okay now I figure out that my issue is caused by a stupid mistake.

I'm using windows 8 and running cmd under the folder c:\scripts.

I'm so new to nodejs and npm that during the set-up process I used `npm install --save-dev jasmine-reporters@^2.0.0` and few days later I used `npm install -g jasmine-reporters@latest`
So there are 2 jasmine-reporters in my system, one in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jasmine-reporters

and another in C:\scripts\node_modules\jasmine-reporters,

with version 2.0.7 and 2.0.0 in package.json, respectively.

I just update my jasmine-reporters in C:\scripts\node_modules to 2.0.7 and the script finally works!

Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i see, there is no fault in your code. If your code is generating chrome and firefox xml's then everything with your configuration should be fine. Your code is working perfectly fine in my protractor. I am using Jasmine 2.3.1 with protractor 2.1.0. Try updating your protractor and jasmine framework to the latest version and then run your test suite. To update your jasmine run the below command -

```
npm update -g jasmine
```

Also if you have not added the framework tag after multiCapabilities tag in your conf.js file then you should be doing so as shown below -

```
framework: 'jasmine2',
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm using Jasmine 2.3.4, and I do have this line 
`framework: 'jasmine2',` 
in my conf.js.
But my firefox.xml and chrome.xml have no difference in testsuite name or testcase classname.

Comment: @Arwin I have almost the exact same `JUnitXmlReporter` initialization and I do see the suite names appended in the resulting XML file. [gist](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/08d321655373ccef44ac).

Comment: @alecxe  I copied your onPrepare to replace mine but still can't see the suite names change accordingly. I'm using protractor 2.1.0 with jasmine-reporters 2.0.7 and jasmine 2.3.4. My spec.js is like
`describe('Demo App', function() {......
it('initializes browser', function() ......`
Now two xml output like _testcase classname="Demo App" name="initializes browser"_

Comment: @Arwin could you create a gist with a complete config you currently have? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Here it is. [link](https://gist.github.com/271519411a3e8958fc6d.git)
Thanks!

Comment: @Arwin your link shows a 404 not found error. Can you please share the correct one?

Comment: @GirishSortur it's just that it should be a gist subdomain: https://gist.github.com/ArwinLin/271519411a3e8958fc6d.

Comment: Right.. gotcha.! thanks alecxe. @Arwin i worked with your gist without making any changes and it works as expected to me.